# Relative velocity summation relationship

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, velocity

We know that the speed of light plus the speed of light is equal to the speed of light, but what about the subtraction, is the speed of light minus the speed of light equal to zero or the speed of light

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are talking about the
[velocity-addition formula of special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity):
$$u = \frac{v+u'}{1+\frac{vu'}{c^2}}$$
where

- $u$ is the velocity of a body in an inertial frame $S$,
- $u'$ is the velocity of that body in another inertial frame $S'$,
- $v$ is the velocity of $S$ relative to $S'$.

You considered the special case with $v=c$ and $u'=-c$.
So you actually get
$$u = \frac{v+u'}{1+\frac{vu'}{c^2}}
 = \frac{c-c}{1+\frac{c(-c)}{c^2}}
 = \frac{0}{0}=\text{undefined}$$
So, what is going on here?

The speed $u'=-c$ is no problem.
This may be just a massless particle (e.g. a photon) moving to the left with the speed of light.
But your choice of $v=c$ is already illegal, because there is no such thing
as a [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) with $|v|=c$.
Only Lorentz transformations with $|v|<c$ are valid.
You cannot have two inertial frames moving with the speed of light
relative to each other.
You can only have two inertial frames moving relative to each other
with a speed *less* than the speed of light.

Comment: Rephrased in terms of rapidity, we have “$\infty+\infty=\infty$“ and “$\infty-\infty=\mbox{undefined}$”.